# Missing Output Exception in rule build_veins

Tags: omnet++, snakemake, veins, sumo

I am trying to run `snakemake -jall` to build the [Serpentine](https://github.com/tkn-tub/serpentine-env/blob/master/examples/Tutorial_Using_the_Serpentine_Scenario.ipynb) scenario.
I get this error:

> MissingOutputException in rule build_veins in file /serpentine-env/Snakefile, line 33:
> Job 9  completed successfully, but some output files are missing. Missing files after 5 seconds. This might be due to filesystem latency. If that is the case, consider to increase the wait time with --latency-wait:
> lib/veins/src/libveins.so

I am using [this](https://github.com/tkn-tub/serpentine-env/blob/master/Snakefile) Snakefile.

Any suggestions?

Increasing the latency-wait does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Rule `build_veins` expects file `lib/veins/src/libveins.so` to be created as output, but it is probably not being created. Check the output files created by line 38.